# Force computer to detect headphones jack

Tags: windows-7, audio, dell-inspiron

I'm on a Dell Inspiron, and recently my headphones jack's detection stopped working. Is there a registry edit or some sort of hack I can do to force the computer to route audio through the headphones jack, even if it doesn't detect headphones? If I hold my headphones a certain way (slightly push down on them) it works, so it's not the jack itself, just the switch. I get that the hardware switch is probably broken but is there any way to get around that? Thanks in advance!

I have Realtek HD Audio / Dell Audio by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Can not comment due to feedback , so I have to use an answer. As far as I can judge , you have a hardware problem. Your headphone jack has a problem and that is why in not detected by the OS. If you could force Windows to route the sound to the port you desire , you still could not hear anything since the jack is broken and the sound( small electric current) could not pass to headphone. Only if ,as you say , hold the device in a certain position you have an electrical contact which allows the current to flow through the headphones. In addition to cover the case of problematic headphones test then elsewhere and test the jack with other headphones as well.