# Force Windows to re-check the headphone jack without a reboot

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, headphones

Misbehaving headphones appear to be a [common problem with Dell Inspiron laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/1150997/force-computer-to-detect-headphones-jack) and generally with Windows computers.

My headphone jack is working correctly, but only if the headphones are plugged in **before** Windows boots. Plug them in **after** Windows has booted, and they are never detected (see image below where the headphones are plugged in).

[image: Headphones plugged in...but not detected]

With the headphones plugged in, simply rebooting the laptop gets them working again. This is sometimes an option, but in the middle of some complicated task can be awkward.

Restarting the `Windows Audio` service has no effect. Re-installing the `Realtek` drivers works one time, then on the next boot cycle the problem happens again.

Is there a way to force Windows to re-check the hardware jack in less "superficial" way, like during the boot cycle? The goal is to get the headphones working without having to reboot the entire computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appear to have found a solution which worked on several tests.

- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand the `Sound, video and game controllers` node (see image)
- Right-click the `Realtek(R) Audio` device and select `Disable device`
- Right-click `Realtek(R) Audio` again and select `Enable device`

[image]

The headphones are now detected and work correctly. Repeat the above procedure if headphones are unplugged. Much less hassle than rebooting the entire machine!

**Update**

**Addendum 1**: When enabling/disabling devices, `Device Manager` may suggest restarting the computer for "changes to take affect". Ignore that!

**Addendum 2**: The `Realtek (R) Audio` device may not actually disable if in use (e.g. playing some music). Close application(s) using the audio device and try again. Disabled devices show a small "down arrow" symbol as the `Dell USB Audio` device does in the image.

Answer (score 0):

This will help :

- Run *Start > Manage sound devices*
- Find the headphones under "Disabled"
- Click on the headphones and then click on Enable.

Comment: My headphones are not disabled, though this might be helpful for someone else. An alternative to this answer is to right-click the volume icon in the tray, then select the `Playback` tab.

Comment: Does Disable followed by Enable help in your case?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is not an answer to my problem, but may be helpful for someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that worked for me.
After plugging in the headphones, the Realtek Audio Console asks if it's a Headset or Headphones - I select Headset.
Then I open the Realtek Audio Console from the start menu, go to Advanced Settings and manually switch from Headset to Headphones -> Headphones working!
After that I can also switch back to Headset and it's still working.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, though not relevant to the question: In your case, the headphones were detected!

Comment: yes and no - they will not appear as a new device in the playback devices, but Realtek somehow realized that I plugged in something...